# join two csv files with key value

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have two csv files, I want to join them using a key value, the column of the city.

One csv file, d01.csv has this form,

```
Barcelona, 19.5, 29.5
Tarragona, 20.4, 31.5 
Girona, 17.2, 32.5
Lleida, 16.5, 33.5 
Vic, 17.5, 31.4
```

The other one, d02.csv, has the next structure,

```
City, Data, TMax, TMin
Barcelona, 20140916, 19.9, 28.5
Tarragona, 20140916, 21.4, 30.5  
Lleida, 20140916, 17.5, 32.5 
Tortosa, 20140916, 20.5, 30.4
```

I need a new csv file, with a column of cities which appear in the 2 csv files.

```
City, Tmin, Tmax, Date, Tmin1, Tmax1
Barcelona, 19.5, 29.5, 20140916, 19.9, 28.5
Tarragona, 20.4, 31.5, 20140916, 21.4, 30.5
Girona, 17.2, 32.5, 20140916, 17.5, 32.5
Lleida, 16.5, 33.5, 20140916, 20.5, 30.4
```

I tried to do that with

```
join -j 2 -t ',' d01.csv d02.csv | awk -F "," '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5} > d03.csv
```

but it is not complete...how can I order the key value?

Comment: Are those leading numbers in the actual files? What is the output of that join command? Are you really trying to invert the `Tmin` and `Tmax` column order as part of this process? Does `d01.csv` really not have a heading line? Are the `Tmax` values supposed to be less than the `Tmin` values in the input files?

Comment: @Jotne I didn't make that edit because I wasn't certain those leading commas in the first file were a mistake. The OP used `-j 2` in the `join` command after all.

Comment: OP If the edit is wrong, please correct it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's how to use join in bash:

```
{
  echo "City, Tmin, Tmax, Date, Tmin1, Tmax1"
  join -t, <(sort d01.csv) <(sed 1d d02.csv | sort)
} > d03.csv
cat d03.csv
```

```
City, Tmin, Tmax, Date, Tmin1, Tmax1
Barcelona, 19.5, 29.5, 20140916, 19.9, 28.5
Lleida, 16.5, 33.5 , 20140916, 17.5, 32.5 
Tarragona, 20.4, 31.5 , 20140916, 21.4, 30.5
```

Note that join only outputs records where the key exists in both files. To get all of them, specify that you want missing records from both files, specify the fields you want, and give a default value for the missing fields:

```
join -t, -a1 -a2 -o 0,1.2,1.3,2.2,2.3,2.4 -e '?' <(sort d01.csv) <(sed 1d d02.csv | sort)
```

```
Barcelona, 19.5, 29.5, 20140916, 19.9, 28.5
Girona, 17.2, 32.5,?,?,?
Lleida, 16.5, 33.5 , 20140916, 17.5, 32.5 
Tarragona, 20.4, 31.5 , 20140916, 21.4, 30.5  
Tortosa,?,?, 20140916, 20.5, 30.4
Vic, 17.5, 31.4,?,?,?
```

Comment: Epic piece of scripting, thanks! In my case it did seem to add some stray carriage returns (which show up in vi as ^M), but that might be related to my source data. The following quick vi command sorts that out: `:%s/\r//g`.

Comment: That command would not have added any carriage returns. They would have come from your input files.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the [CSV Cruncher](https://github.com/OndraZizka/csv-cruncher) which takes CSV files as SQL tables and then allows SQL queries, resulting in another CSV file.

Example:

```
crunch input.csv output.csv \
   "SELECT AVG(duration) AS durAvg FROM (SELECT * FROM indata ORDER BY duration LIMIT 2 OFFSET 6)"
```

The tool needs Java 5 or later.

Some of the advantages:

- You really get CSV support, not just "let's assume the data is correct".
- You can join on multiple keys.
- Easier to use and understand than `join`-based solutions.
- You can combine more than 2 CSV files.
- You can join by SQL expressions - the values don't have to be the same.

Disclaimer: I wrote that tool. Unknown project state - Google Code was closed and I didn't transfer it soon enough. I might have a look at it if someone is insterested.

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` may do:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2FS$3FS$4;next} $1 in a {print $0,a[$1]}' OFS=", " d02,csv d01csv
Barcelona, 19.5, 29.5, 20140916, 19.9, 28.5
Tarragona, 20.4, 31.5 , 20140916, 21.4, 30.5
Lleida, 16.5, 33.5 , 20140916, 17.5, 32.5
```

Comment: it runs also, but could you explain me this structure? I will apreciate it

Comment: @EnricAgudPique `FNR==NR` run this for first file `d02.csv` (store data from file to an array `a` using first field as index.  Then if first field is found in the next file `$1 in a` print needed output.  This is a common way to handle two files in `awk`.