# Join two .csv files

Tags: java, database, csv, join, merge

I want to join two CSV files in the way shown below.
The files always have the same structure (e.g. there is always three products in the cart).

"Database":

```
ProductId, Name, Price
123, "My Product 1", 99
223, "My Product 2", 42
323. "My Product 3", 19
```

"Shopping-Cart":

```
 CustomerId, Product1, Product2, Product3
 111, 123, 223, 323
 112, 223, 223, 123
```

Wanted Output:

```
CustomerId, Product1, Product1Name, Product1Price, Product2, Product2Name, Product2Price, Product3, Product3Name, Product3Price
111, 123, "My Product1", 99, 223, "My Product 2", 42, 323, "My Product 3", 19
112, 223, "My Product2", 41, 223, "My Product 2", 42, 123, "My Product 1", 99
```

I thought about solving this with a small Java-Programm using a CSV library and than manually processing the files. But I wonder if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question, can you please post what you have tried so far so we can see your thought process.

Comment: What have you tried in detail so far? this can be solved btw on shell with one command: join

Comment: You can't "join" files in SQL. You need to put that data into a (relational) database first if you want to "join" them.

Comment: If you really just want to join the data as an one-time-operation I would just use something like Access or Base. The approach to create DDL, read and store data, just to do a SQL statement on the data seems a bit overcomplicating things; functional extensions to languages like LINQ or FlatMap in Java could get the job also done

Comment: I'd like to have a bash command or maybe a little tool that does the job in an automated way. 
I could write a tool using sqlite that imports the csv files to the database and runs the sql command afterwards. @frlan can you be more specific on the join bash command?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875368/join-two-csv-files-with-key-value

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work on the CSV files without using a database in intermediate step (which anyway would be the better solution in this case) you might use the [CSV file JDBC driver](https://sourceforge.net/projects/csvjdbc/).

Find below a snippet to show the principle. (note: No further investigation has been done other then needed to prepare the snippet.)

assume following directories and files

```
bin/
csv.directory/database.csv
csv.directory/shopping_cart.csv
lib/csvjdbc-1.0-31.jar
src/sub/optimal/Main.java
```

**database.csv**

```
ProductId, Name, Price
123,"My Product 1",99
223,"My Product 2",42
323,"My Product 3",19
```

**shopping_cart.csv**

```
111,123,223,323
112,223,223,123
```

**Main.java**

```
import java.sql.*;
import org.relique.jdbc.csv.CsvDriver;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        String csvDirectory = "csv.directory";
        String connURL = "jdbc:relique:csv:";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL + csvDirectory);
        try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
            String sql;
            sql = "SELECT c.CustomerId,"
                    + "       c.Product1,"
                    + "       (SELECT name"
                    + "        FROM database AS d"
                    + "        WHERE d.ProductId = c.Product1"
                    + "       ) AS Product1Name,"
                    + "       (SELECT price"
                    + "        FROM database AS d"
                    + "        WHERE d.ProductId = c.Product1"
                    + "       ) AS Product1Price"
                    + " FROM shopping_cart AS c";
            ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            boolean append = true;
            CsvDriver.writeToCsv(results, System.out, append);
        }
    }
}
```

**compile**

```
javac -d bin/ -cp lib/* src/sub/optimal/Main.java
```

**run**

```
java -cp bin:lib/* sub.optimal.Main
```

**output**

```
CustomerId,Product1,PRODUCT1NAME,PRODUCT1PRICE
111,123,My Product 1,99
112,223,My Product 2,42
```

Comment: Beware that csvjdbc has a limitation that it does not support JOIN queries, but only sub-queries (as shown in the example above).  If you wish to use a JOIN, you can use the "export data" wizard of DBeaver from a CSV file (using csvjdbc), and select a SQL database to import the data into it.

Answer (score 0):

Joining tables is what DBMS - Database Management Systems - typically do. While you could write this yourself, it is probably simply and easier to use a free-software DBMS (such as [MonetDB](http://www.monetdb.org/), [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/) or [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/)): Load the two CSV files into tables of the DBMS; write a join query:

```
SELECT cart_with_product_info AS
  c.CustomerId,
  c.Product1,
  p1.Name AS Product1Name,
  p1.Price AS Product1Price,
  c.Product2,
  p2.Price AS Product2Name,
  p2.Price AS Product2Price,
  c.Product3,
  p3.Name AS Product3Name,
  p3.Price Product3Price
FROM 
  shopping_cart AS c,
  products AS p1,
  products AS p2,
  products AS p3
WHERE
  p1.ProductId = c.Product1
  AND p2.ProductId = c.Product2
  AND p3.ProductId = c.Product3;
```

run it and get the results as a CSV (several way to do this, e.g. programmatically or using the command-line client).