# join two csv file using column reference

Tags: shell, csv, join

I have two csv files 
file 1 :

```
firstName    lastName     internalId      email         phoneNumber
XX           YY           123             xx@mail.fr    003312345600
ZZ           QQ           147             zz@mail.fr    003371236500
KK           JJ           159             kk@mail.fr    003369865300
```

file 2 :

```
internalId    email        phoneNumber
159           ss@mail.fr   003379632500
147           ee@mail.fr   003396325200
```

i like to join file 1 and file 2 to have this result

```
firstName    lastName     internalId      email         phoneNumber
XX           YY           123             xx@mail.fr    003312345600
ZZ           QQ           147             ee@mail.fr    003396325200
KK           JJ           159             ss@mail.fr    003369865300
```

modify email and phoneNumber if it finds the same internalId if not I keep the same values

Answer (score 1):

**awk** solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$1]=$2 FS $3; next }
     FNR>1 && ($3 in a){ split(a[$3], b); $4=b[1]; $5=b[2] }1' file2 file1 | column -t
```

- `NR==FNR` - processing the 1st input file i.e. `file2`
- `a[$1]=$2 FS $3` - fill the array `a` with concatenated values of the 2nd `$2` and 3rd field `$3` of file `file2`(i.e. `email` and `phoneNumber`) indexing it with the 1st field value `$1`, i.e. `internalId`
- `FNR>1 && ($3 in a)` - processing the 2nd input file `file1`, making substitutions on matched `internalId`s

---

The output:

```
firstName  lastName  internalId  email       phoneNumber
XX         YY        123         xx@mail.fr  003312345600
ZZ         QQ        147         ee@mail.fr  003396325200
KK         JJ        159         ss@mail.fr  003379632500
```

Comment: with shell  please

Comment: @Golden, don't tell that your system doesn't have `awk` installed

Comment: @Romain, Yes i have

Comment: @Romain, but I do not master awk well
can you explain to me the first line please

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you need to do this in shell from your tags

Looks like a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875368/join-two-csv-files-with-key-value). [Join](https://shapeshed.com/unix-join/) command is your friend here