# how to compare 2 csv file base on multiple columns awk?

Tags: awk

I have 2 csv file with sample format as below ,, have ~ 5000 rows in each files :

file 1:

```
    EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME,MIDDLE_NAME,BRANCH,DEPARTMENT,LEVEL,POSITION,EMAIL_ADDRESS
110426,Balbon,Susan,Lagat,"abc Equity Ventures, Inc.",Group Internal Audit,Supervisor,I.S. Audit Supervisor,susan.balbon@abc.com
30083,Mendezona,Bingen,Roemer,"abc Equity Ventures, Inc.",Risk Management Office,Vice President,VP - AEV Security,bing.mendezona@abc.test
110773,Casas,Joyce Grace,Bea,"abc Equity Ventures, Inc.",Tax Advisory and Compliance,Manager,Tax Counsel,joyce.grace.casas@abc.com
286,Fernandez,Mark Brian,Tato,abc Foundation Inc.,Computer Services Division,Supervisor,Senior Applications Supervisor,mark.fernandez@abc.com
291,Plando,Marilou,Polleros,"abc Equity Ventures, Inc.",Administration,Assistant Vice President,AVP - Risk Management,marilou.plando@abc.test
110813,Gemelo-Abarca,Therese Xyza,Dableo,"abc Equity Ventures, Inc.",Governance & Compliance Team,Manager,Associate General Counsel - Corporate Secretarial and Compliance,therese.xyza.abarca@abc.com
30096,Abay,Joanna Marie,Saluria,"abc Equity Ventures, Inc.",Tax Advisory and Compliance,Supervisor,Tax Compliance Officer,joanna.abay@abc.com
110711,Ostan,Margilyn,Salibio,"abc Equity Ventures, Inc.",Accounting,Staff,Senior Accountant 1,margilyn.ostan@abc.com
110732,Fumar-Gonzales,Vanessa Concepcion,Altarejos,"abc Equity Ventures, Inc.",Legal and Corporate Services,Manager,Associate General Counsel - Labor & Litigation,vanessa.gonzales@abc.com
```

file 2 :

```
    EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME,MIDDLE_NAME,BRANCH,DEPARTMENT,LEVEL,POSITION,EMAIL_ADDRESS
110426,Balbon,Susan,Lagat,"abc Equity Ventures, Inc.",Group Internal Audit,Supervisor,I.S. Audit Supervisor,susan.balbon@abc.com
30083,Mendezona,Bingen,Roemer,"abc Equity Ventures, Inc.",Security,Vice President,VP - AEV Security,jetee.velante@abc.com
110773,Casas,Joyce Grace,Bea,"abc Equity Ventures, Inc.",Tax Advisory and Compliance,Supervisor,Tax Counsel,joyce.grace.casas@abc.com
286,Fernandez,Mark Brian,Tato,abc Foundation Inc.,Computer Services Division,Supervisor,Senior Applications Supervisor,mark.fernandez@abc.com
291,Plando,Marilou,Polleros,"abc Equity Ventures, Inc.",Risk Management Office,Assistant Vice President,AVP - Risk Management,marilou.plando@abc.test
110866,Dugan,Belinda,Escultura,"abc Equity Ventures, Inc.",Legal Management,Vice President,Vice President for Legal Services Management,dixie.dugan@abc.test
221,Montehermoso,Gladys,Enoy,"abc Equity Ventures, Inc.",Accounting,Staff,Senior Accountant,gladys.montehermoso@abc.com
30102,Oblianda,Anna Cielo,Salud,"abc Equity Ventures, Inc.",Accounting,Supervisor,Accounting Supervisor,cielo.oblianda@abc.com
110499,Bucol,Charmaine Ann,Rebusa,"abc Equity Ventures, Inc.",Group Internal Audit,Staff,Audit Senior,charmaine.ann.bucol@abc.com
```

I would like to file all row have same  value in EMPLOYEE_NUMBER+EMAIL_ADDRESS columns but have different values in others columns using awk.

My ideal is merge 2 csv file base on columns EMPLOYEE_NUMBER+EMAIL_ADDRESS  on vertical and remove duplicated row using awk. Thanks

Output will like that :

```
EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME,MIDDLE_NAME,BRANCH,DEPARTMENT,LEVEL,POSITION,EMAIL_ADDRESS
110773,Casas,Joyce Grace,Bea,"Aboitiz Equity Ventures, Inc.",Tax Advisory and Compliance,Manager,Tax Counsel,joyce.grace.casas@aboitiz.com
110773,Casas,Joyce Grace,Bea,"Aboitiz Equity Ventures, Inc.",Tax Advisory and Compliance,Supervisor,Tax Counsel,joyce.grace.casas@aboitiz.com
```

Comment: post the final expected result

Comment: Please use a simplified example, that is please remove all columns which are not absolutely necessary to ask your question. While this might not be your original problem, it will probably be a much better question.

Comment: Are those real personal data, you should probably not share them on the internet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [join two csv files with key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875368/join-two-csv-files-with-key-value)

Comment: @Inian why would bash not be a suitable tag? I think it is.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann: Bash is not a _recommended_ way for line by line text processing. More over, OP clearly necessities an use for `awk`

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann thanks.. but it's oke which sample data .

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann join is support with multiple columns ? and i need join by vertical.

Comment: why shouldn't this record `30083,Mendezona,Bingen,Roem ...` be in the output (if does fit your conditions)?

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

Use simple awk_script can achieve that,

awk_script:

```
NR==FNR{
  if(FNR==1){print}
  a[$1 $2]=$0
  next
}
a[$1 $2]!=$0 && a[$1 $2]!=""{
  print a[$1 $2],$0
}
```

Command to be executed,

```
awk -F',' -v OFS="\n" -f awk_script file1 file2
```

Comment: Then please help to check my answer as acceptance. :)